# Prove $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{ N} }{\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]} = [0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

First, I apologize for my English, it is not my native language.

To solve this exercise I started by proving that 
$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{ N} }{\left[0,1-\frac{1}
 {n}\right]} \subseteq [0,1)$:

Let $x \displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{ N} }{\left[0,1-\frac{1}
 {n}\right]}$.

Therefore, there exist some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$x \in \left[0,1-\frac{1}{N}\right]$

Since $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{N} > 0$. (Note that in my case the natural numbers start at 1)

Thus $0 \leq x \leq 1- \frac{1}{N} < 1$,

Then $x \in [0,1)$

This is, $\left[0,1-\frac{1}{N}\right] \subseteq [0,1)$

Then, $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{ N} }{\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]} \subseteq [0,1)$.

### Edit

(I used the suggestions received to finish the second part of the proof. **Is this well?**)

To obtain the opposite inclusion, suppose $x\subseteq [0,1)$ and choose $ \varepsilon =1-x >0$.

By the Archimedean property follows that there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$\frac{1}{N}<1-x$

Thus, $0 \leqslant x<1-\frac{1}{N}$.

Therefore, $x \in \left[0,1-\frac{1}{N}\right]$.

This means, $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{ N} }{\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]}$.

We conclude that
$[0,1) \subseteq \displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{ N} }{\left[0,1-\frac{1}
 {n}\right]}$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Hello @5xum. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Hint: if $a>0$ then can you prove that $0<\frac1n<a$ for some positive integer $n$? Do this for $a=1-x$ where $x\in[0,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first part of the proof is... OK. It's not perfect. It has some flaws where, sure, because the statement is simple, I know what you were *trying* to say, but you didn't really say that, and you didn't make your intention clear. For example:

> I started by proving that
>
> $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{ N} }{\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]} \subseteq [0,1)$.
>
> I tried it this way:
>
> Let $x\in \left[0,1-\frac{1} {N}\right]$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Why did you select this $x$? Usually, when we are proving $A\subseteq B$, we must take some $x\in A$, but you didn't do that. You selected $x$ from a *subset* of $A$.

Instead, the beginning of your proof should be something like this:

> Let $$x\in \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[0, 1-\frac1n\right].$$ Therefore, there **exists** some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $$x\in\left[0, 1-\frac1N\right].$$

The rest of this part of the proof is then OK.

---

To prove the second part, you need to prove that if $x\in[0,1)$, then $$x\in \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[0, 1-\frac1n\right].$$ To do that, think about what $x<1$ means, and try to find some $N$ such that $x<1-\frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: I made the corrections and tried to finish the proof. Is it correct now?

Comment: @DannyAlzate Better. The line "This is, $\left[0,1-\frac{1}{N}\right] \subseteq [0,1)$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$", however, is redundant. Your proof stands without it. The proof in the other direction is well done.

Comment: @5xum:  in the second highlighted portion, did you mean to say    "Therefore, there **exists** some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\color{red}{x\in}\left[0, 1-\frac1N\right].$"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, of course.